# OpenGL Multidimensional Array Penalties

Tags: c#, arrays, opengl, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to decide the best way to store information in VBO's for OpenGL. I've been reading about how matricies are stored as single-dimensional arrays because of the performance penalties of using multi-dimensional arrays.

I was wondering, does this extend to storing information in VBO's?  does it make more sense to store vertex information within VBOs in single or multidimensional arrays?

Before I get a bunch of answers saying it depends on what I'm storing, I'm talking specifically about things that would traditionally be considered for multidimensional arrays (maps, grids, etc....).

what type of performance hits would I be looking at by using the multidimensional arrays if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is invalid, as it makes no sense. Buffer objects are blocks of memory stored and managed by OpenGL. It's not a C# array or a C# multi-dimensional array. It's a block of memory that you transfer data into.

The vertex data you put into a buffer object must conform with what [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) allows. How you achieve that in C# is up to you and whatever API you use.

Comment: ok that makes sense.   i wasn't sure because i saw so many books, etc... that talk against them, but I guess it only applies to matricies, since OpenGL works with them for specific functions, as oppossed to just reading and writing to them

Comment: one question I have, then, is about jagged arrays.  do they have to be added to a VBO differently than multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @DavidTorrey: What part of "How you achieve that in C# is up to you and whatever API you use," do you not understand? OpenGL doesn't know about C# jagged arrays, C# multi-dimensional arrays, or anything else. It knows about *bytes*. You give it a series of unformatted bytes, and then you tell it how to interpret that byte stream using the given function. How you take a C# data structure and turn it into the series of bytes that you give to OpenGL depends on your OpenGL interface code.

Answer (score 0):

> are stored as single-dimensional arrays because of the performance penalties of using multi-dimensional arrays.

I think your confusion stems from differences in terminology regarding multidimensional arrays and how they can be represented.

In C an array is accessed through pointer dereferencing:

```
int arr[10];

arr[5] <--> *(arr+5)
```

In fact the indexing operator `o[i]` fully equivalent to `*(o+i)` and you can actually also write `i[o]`, because it yields the same expression. So the index operator does pointer arithmetic and dereferences. What does this mean for C multidim arrays:

```
int marr[10][10];

int (*row)[10] = marr[5] <--> *(marr + 5);

mrow[5] = *(mrow + 5) <--> marr[5][5];
```

And you can expand this for as many dimensions as you like. So, in C multidimensional arrays go through multiple pointer dereferences, which may also mean, that the data is not contigous in memory, and in face may have different sizes for each row. And that's why they are inefficient. C does this that was, to allow for dynamic allocation of the column pointers and the rows.

However the other way to store multidimensional arrays is a flat storage model. I.e. you just concatenate all the elements into one single string of values. And by introducing dimensions you know, where to cut this string to rearrange it.

```
int fmarr[10*20*30];

int at1_2_3 = fmarr[1*30*20 + 2*20 + 3];
```

As you can see all sizes are static, and the data is contigous. There are no pointer dereferences, which makes working with the data much simpler and more importantly allows for vectorization of the operations. This makes things much more performant.